# Differential equation of a path

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation of a path of a particle is $$\frac{d^2 u}{d \theta^2}-\frac{5}{4}u=\frac{9}{4}\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}$$ where $u=\frac{1}{r}$ and $r$ is distance from origin to a particle, $\alpha,\beta=\text{const}.$

I've got that solution of this DE is $$u=C_1e^{\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}\theta}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}\theta}-\frac{9\alpha}{5\beta^2}$$
Initial conditions are $r=\frac{\beta^2}{3\alpha}$ and $\theta=0$ at moment $t=0$. Also, I know that $\frac{du}{d\theta}(0)=-\frac{3\sqrt 3\alpha}{\beta^2}$

From these initial conditions I found constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.

I have to show that a particle will return to its initial position after one revolution around $O$ and then fly off to infinity.

How can I do this?

Comment: After one revolution, we have $\theta = 2\pi$, so you just have to check that $u(0) = u(2\pi)$. Also, I believe the exponents in the solution are supposed to be $\pm\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}\theta$, not $\pm\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}\theta}$ (the square root sign isn't supposed to cover $\theta$).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I made a typing mistake. I corrected it. I know that $u(2\pi)$ should satisfy initial conditions, but how can I be sure that there will be only one revolution?

Comment: You can be sure since the function only has one minimum, and no maximum. If you can argue (well enough) why this is and why this results in only two $\theta$'s with the same $u$-value, then I'm pretty sure most teachers would give you full marks on your homework, depending on their definition of "well enough".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is slightly misleading: you are not trying to match $u(2 \pi)$ with $u(0)$.  Rather, you are just trying to show that there is another $\theta$ for which $u(\theta)=u(0)$.  This is easily done.

I will skip the algebra in matching the initial conditions and produce the solution explicitly:

$$\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha} u(\theta) = \frac{3}{5} \left (4-\sqrt{15}\right) e^{\sqrt{5} \theta/2} + \frac{3}{5} \left (4+\sqrt{15}\right) e^{-\sqrt{5} \theta/2} - \frac{9}{5}$$

We wish to solve $u(\theta) = 3 \alpha/\beta^2$ for $\theta$.  As you can probably surmise, this leads to a quadratic:

$$\left (4-\sqrt{15}\right) y^2 - 8 y + \left (4+\sqrt{15}\right)=0$$

where $y=e^{\sqrt{5} \theta/2}$.  The solutions are $y=1$, for which $\theta=0$ as expected, and

$$y=\frac{4+\sqrt{15}}{4-\sqrt{15}} = \left ( 4+\sqrt{15}\right)^2$$

or

$$\theta = \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}} \log{\left ( 4+\sqrt{15}\right)} \approx 3.6932$$

So this returns to its initial point not really after a full revolution, but perhaps a little more than a quarter turn.

As for shooting off to infinity, that is some $\theta$ for which $u(\theta)=0$.  This is another quadratic:

$$\left (4-\sqrt{15}\right) y^2 - 3 y + \left (4+\sqrt{15}\right)=0$$

Here, I get both positive solutions, and the corresponding $\theta$ occur prior to the value I found above, which doesn't fit into the narrative of the problem.

Comment: Is it $y=e^{\sqrt{5}\theta}$ or $y=e^{{\sqrt{5} \theta}/2}$?

Comment: @gov: you are right, it is the latter.  I will fix as soon as possible.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood why does it fly off to infinity after one revolution. Would you explain that?

Comment: @gov: physically or mathematically?  Mathematically, I think I explained in the last part of my solution.

Comment: Then physically. I found those solutions for $u(\theta)=0$ and I know why does it hold (because $u=\frac{1}{r}$ and $r$ goes to infinity.)

Comment: @gov: If you work out the original Binet equation, you see that your equation results from a central force $$F(r) = \frac{9}{4} \frac{\ell}{r^2} - \frac{9}{4} \frac{\alpha}{\beta^2} \frac{\ell}{r^3}$$ So it appears you have a $1/r^2$ repulsive component and a weaker $1/r^3$ attractive component.  Starting sufficiently far enough from the origin means that the repulsive component will dominate the orbit and the particle will shoot off to infinity.

Comment: What is $\ell$?

Comment: @gov: angular momentum, which is fixed in such a system.

Comment: Ok, it's clearer to me now. Thank you! :)